# Error to connect Postgresql DB from Oracle dblink using Oracle Database Gateway

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ssl

I'm trying to connect from Oracle Database (dblink) to Postgresql database use Oracle Database Gateway (dg4msql 19), on the Oracle Database Gateway for MS SQL Server all work fine. On the Oracle DB create dblink, but when try to connect get Error message:

```
ORA-28500 Oracle ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver Socket closed 
08S01 Oracle ODBC SQL Server Wire protocol driver
The server does not support SSL {HY000} !
```

listener work, `tnsnames.ora` also give correct answer. May be in `initdg4msql.ora` file I have to use some string to connect without SSL?

`HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = postgre_servet.net:5432//database` - I don`t known that is correct for PostgreSQL, or for PostgreSQL should use only ODBC connection?

How correctly use `HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = postgre_servet.net:5432//database`, or for PostgreSQL should I use only ODBC connection?

Comment: I am not sure that I follow.  Are you trying to use a SQL Server wire protocol ODBC driver to connect to a PostgreSQL database?  Why wouldn't you use a PostgreSQL ODBC driver?

Comment: I never setup Oracle Database Gatewey for PostgreSQL and why dont known can i use connection string like for MS SQL Server or only one way exists and its ODBC ?

Comment: You can't use SQL Server infrastructure to connect to a non-SQL Server database.  It doesn't make sense to use the SQL Server gateway and the SQL Server ODBC driver to connect to a PostgreSQL database.  You can use generic connectivity and a PostgreSQL ODBC driver to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Thanks Jastin, did I understand you correctly, i should create odbc.ini like that
`
[TEST_PSQL]

Description = PostgreSQL database 
Driver  = postgresql
Username = zbx_test
Password = zabbix

# Name of Server. IP or DNS
Servername = 127.0.0.1
# Database name
Database = zabbix
# Postmaster listening port
Port = 5432
# Database is read only
`

And then in initdg4msql.ora use some string:
 HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = TEST_PSQL ?

Comment: _"nd then in initdg4msql.ora"_  NO!  You cannot use anything of mssql to connect to a database that is not mssql.  If you want to connect to postgreSQL, then you must use postgreSQL drivers.  And your initdg* file must be for postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL server is not configured to accept SSL connections.

First, verify that PostgreSQL was built with SSL support: that can be seen from the output of `pg_config --configure` (should contain `--with-openssl`).

To configure SSL support, set `ssl = on` in `postgresql.conf` and provide a server certificate and private key (parameters `ssl_vert_file` and `ssl_key_file`). Reload PostgreSQL to activate.

For details, read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).

Comment: I think that it`s not error on PostgreSQL server side, but tnanks for answer.